# In (neo)vim, how can I jump to the start or end of a text object?

Tags: vim, neovim

I am familiar with how I can change, delete, yank etc inside or around various text objects.

I would like to jump to the start or end of the current sentence, or any other text object I currently in.

Is there some command to do this?

Comment: How much general would like it to be? When giving a <c/d/y><i/a><object>, you also need to be specific about the nature of the object.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic command for that.

That said, doing `v<text-object><Esc>` leaves the cursor at the end of the text object, and doing `v<text-object>o<Esc>` leaves the cursor at the start. `vip<Esc>` or `vipo<Esc>` are not so bad.

See `:help v_o`.

If you feel adventurous, you may consider using that base technique to build your own custom motions.